# Canadian Postal Code validation

Tags: validation, regular-expressions

I'm trying to bring together LEN and Regex but it's not working.

I need to validate CDN postal code on the opportunity.

We can only accept all caps and a space for a total of 7 characters

I was working with the below:

LEN( Postal_Code__c ) < 7

With

NOT( OR( ISBLANK(Postal_Code__c), REGEX( Postal_Code__c , "[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY1234567890]{3}[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY1234567890]{3}") ) )

But unable to combine them properly to get this fully working.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `LEN` check if you let the `REGEX` do the work for you

```
NOT(
  OR(
    ISBLANK( Postal_Code__c ), 
    REGEX( Postal_Code__c , 
           "^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$"
    )
  )
)
```

---

I internet searched and found this...

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/regex/canada-postal-code-validation/

..and just copied/pasted the Regex I found there into your code.

I tested with the examples from that same page, as well as adding additional characters.

That page states:

> In Above regex, the negative lookahead at the beginning of this regular expression prevents D, F, I, O, Q, or U anywhere in the subject string. The <[A-VXY]> character class further prevents W or Z as the first character.

To further elaborate:

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- Everything inside `(?!)` is the negative lookahead which is explained above

  - `.` any character
  - `*` zero or more times
  - Everything inside the `[]` is a grouping of those characters
- Each grouping of `[]` allows for one and only one of the characters in the group
- The space + question mark  `?` allows for *zero or one space*, SO IF YOU *REQUIRE* THE SPACE **then you need to remove the question mark and leave the space**
- Each grouping of `[]` again allows only one of the group characters
- `$` matches the end of the string

---

The linked page also states:

> A valid canadian postcode is –
>
> - in the format A1A 1A1, where A is a letter and 1 is a digit.
> - a space separates the third and fourth characters.
> - do not include the letters D, F, I, O, Q or U.
> - the first position does not make use of the letters W or Z.

As long as what that page states is a valid Canadian Postal Code is correct (I have no clue), then this should work.

---

*NOTE: You can copy/paste any Regex you find, or enter your own, at https://regexr.com and it will break it down for you and explain it.*

Comment: thanks for your help!